# System.InvalidOperationException: 'Invalid attempt to call FieldCount when reader is closed.'

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

I have this class that tries to read from the sql reader

```
        using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
    using MinimalAPI.Models.ConnectUI;

    namespace ConnectAPI.SQL.BAL
    {
        public class ConnectData
        {
            public static Form Get_Froms_Data(int form_Id, string page_Id = null)
            {
                Form form = new Form();
                SqlDataReader reader = ConnectAPI.SQL.DAL.ConnectData.Get_Froms_Data(form_Id, page_Id);
                foreach(var row in reader) <-- where the error occurs
                {


                    var t = "";

                }
                reader.Close();
                return form;
            }
        }
    }
```

And this class to access dal call:

```
        using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
    using MinimalAPI.Models.ConnectUI;
    using System.Data;

    namespace ConnectAPI.SQL.DAL
    {
        public class ConnectData
        {
            static string sqlconnectionstring = "xxx";

            public static SqlDataReader Get_Froms_Data(int form_Id, string page_Id = null)
            {
                string procedurename = "getFormData";
                SqlDataReader reader = null;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sqlconnectionstring))
                {
                    con.Open();

                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(procedurename, con))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@formId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = form_Id;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@pageId", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = page_Id;
                        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    }
                    con.Close();
                }

                return reader;
            }

        }
    }
```

but i keep getting the error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Invalid attempt to call FieldCount when reader is closed.'
```

Comment: The reader needs an open connection. Therefore, closing the connection closes the reader, too.

Comment: how could i get around it

Comment: Change the return type to `IEnumerable<IDataRecord>`, where you loop through the reader inside the method and use a `yield return` iterator block to return the reader on each iteration. Be careful, though: this is the _same object_ for each iteration, just mutated, and strange things can happen if you're not careful. Because of this, I might also also add an argument to the method to accept a lambda to construct an object from the reader.

Comment: Consider using Dapper so you can have the method return an `IEnumerable` or `IList` of typed objects, and save on a bunch of boilerplate to boot.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn that's generally how we do those sorts of methods (when we're not using Dapper): pass a `Func<SqlDataReader, T>` method in, and return an `IEnumerable<T>` out

Comment: i removed con.close() and i still get the same error

Comment: I have an answer now to demonstrate my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reader needs an open connection. Therefore, closing the connection effectively closes the reader, too. To get around it, you can start by changing it to return `IEnumerable<IDataRecord>` via an iterator block, like this:

```
public class ConnectData
{
    static string sqlconnectionstring = "xxx";

    public static IEnumerable<IDataRecord> Get_Froms_Data(int form_Id, string page_Id = null)
    {
        string procedurename = "getFormData";

        using var con = new SqlConnection(sqlconnectionstring);
        using var cmd = new SqlCommand(procedurename, con);
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@formId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = form_Id;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@pageId", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = page_Id;
        con.Open();

        using var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            yield return reader;                
        }
    }
}
```

But there is still an issue here, in that we are yielding the *same object* over and over as it mutates. This can have some strange or unexpected consequences. We can fix this by making sure to construct a new object before returning to other code and yielding the new object. We can also improve this to reduce the amount of boilerplate needed for each method.

```
public class ConnectData
{
    static string sqlconnectionstring = "xxx";

    // notice this is private
    private static IEnumerable<IDataRecord> GetSQLData(string sql, Action<SqlParameterCollection> addParams, bool AsProcedure = true)
    {
        using var con = new SqlConnection(sqlconnectionstring);
        using var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        if (AsProcedure) cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        if (addParams is object) addParams(cmd.Parameters);
        con.Open();

        using var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            yield return reader;                
        }
    }

    // I don't know what kind of item you're returning here, had to make it up
    public static IEnumerable<FormItem> Get_Forms_Data(int form_Id, string page_Id = null)
    {        
        string procedurename = "getFormData";
        var data = GetSqlData(procedureName, p => {
                p.Add("@formId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = form_Id;
                p.Add("@pageId", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = page_Id;
            }, true);

        foreach(var row in data)
        {
            // again: I don't know what your records look like
            yield return new FormItem( row["column"]);    
        }
    }
}
```